# logic applied to pointer to string array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I recently came across this question in an Interview process.
I need some help to understand the logic behind 2nd output of this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *c[] = {"GeksQuiz", "MCQ", "TEST", "QUIZ"};
char **cp[] = {c+3, c+2, c+1, c};
char ***cpp = cp;

int main()
{
    printf("%s ", **++cpp);     //1st statement
    printf("%s ", *--*++cpp+3);  //2nd statement
    printf("%s ", *cpp[-2]+3);    //3rd statement
    printf("%s ", cpp[-1][-1]+1);  //4th statement
    return 0;
}
```

output:- `TEST sQuiz Z CQ`

What I understand from above code:

for the sake of simplicity we can consider `cp[]` as {QUIZ TEST MCQ GeksQuiz}
1st statement:
`**++cpp` -> `cpp` will points to base address of `TEST` and dereferencing it 2 times gives `TEST` which is fine.

but in 2nd statement I can't demystify the logic:
`*--*++cpp+3` -> `++cpp` points to `MCQ` `*++cpp` will be the address of `M` , `--*++cpp` will be previous address to `M`, now I'm stuck here. how it's getting `sQuiz` as output?
(afaik ++(suffix) and * have same precedence and right to left associativity)

(DISCLAIMER: please broaden your mind. not all codes are meant for product development. this code evaluates the understanding of C pointers)

Comment: **Moderator Note** I've purged the comments, if you feel the need to continue the off-topic conversation please take it to chat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After first `printf`, `cpp` is pointing to `c+2`.

```
                 CP
              +------+                                                                     
              |      |                                                                     
            0 |  C+3 +----------------------------------------------------------------+    
              |      |                                                                   |    
              |      |                                                                |    
              +------+                                                                |    
              |      |                                                                |    
            1 |  C+2 +-------------------------------------------------+              |    
CPP --------> |      |                                                 |              |    
              |      |                                                 |              |    
              +------+                                                 |              |    
              |      +---------------------------------------+         |              |    
            2 |  C+1 |                                       |         |              |    
              |      |                                       |         |              |    
              |      |                                       |         |              |    
              +------+                                       |         |              |    
              |      +-----------------------+               |         |              |    
            3 |  C   |                       v               v         v              v    
              |      |                                                                     
              |      |                +-------------+------------+-----------+------------+
              +------+             C  |  "GeksQuiz" | "MCQ"      | "TEST"    | "QUIZ"     |       
                                      |             |            |           |            |
                                      +-------------+------------+-----------+------------+
                                        0             1           2            3
```

In second `printf`, `++cpp` will increment `cpp` to `c+1`.
`*++cpp` will dereference `cpp` and will give `c+1`.
`--` will decrement `c+1` by `1` therefore, `*--*++cpp` will ultimately give `c`.
 `c+3` will point to the 4<sup>th</sup> character of `"GeksQuiz"`, i.e. `s`.
Note that after second `printf` `cpp` will point to `cp[0]` which is pointing to `c` now.

```
              +------+                                                                     
              |      |                                                                     
            0 |  C+3 +----------------------------------------------------------------+    
              |      |                                                                   |    
              |      |                                                                |    
              +------+                                                                |    
              |      |                                                                |    
            1 |  C+2 +-------------------------------------------------+              |    
              |      |                                                 |              |    
              |      |                                                 |              |    
              +------+                                                 |              |    
              |      +-------------------------+                       |              |    
            2 |  C   |                         |                       |              |    
 CPP -------->|      |                         |                       |              |    
              |      |                         |                       |              |    
              +------+                         |                       |              |                                                  
              |      +-----------------------+ |                       |              |    
            3 |  C   |                       v v                       v              v    
              |      |                                                                     
              |      |                +-------------+------------+-----------+------------+
              +------+                |  "GeksQuiz" | "MCQ"      | "TEST"    | "QUIZ"     |
                                      |             |            |           |            |
                                      +-------------+------------+-----------+------------+
                                        0             1           2            3
```

Comment: thnks.so after 2nd stmnt, cpp should be poiting to base address of Geksquiz. now for *cpp[-2]+3 -> *cpp[-2] points 2 pos back i.e. TEST but it is pointing 3 pos back i.e.QUIZ

Comment: After second `printf` statement, `cpp` is pointing to `c+1`. `cpp[-2]` is pointing to `cpp - 2`, i.e. at `c+3`.

Comment: @haccks Yes after the second statement `cpp` is pointing to where `c+1` was originally, but the value of that element is now just `c`.  Not that it matters since that element is never accessed again.

Comment: @MooseBoys; That's what my answer says.

Comment: @haccks But your second diagram still has a `c+1` in it - shouldn't it be `c` instead?

Comment: @MooseBoys; Yes. Edited that. I am not good in drawing ASCII arts :)

Answer (score 4):

`*--*++cpp+3` is processed as `*(--(*(++cpp)))+3` which means the following:

`*++cpp` points to `"MCQ"` (due to initial move of the pointer to "next in list" twice), was pointing to `"TEST"` after the first `printf` was over

`--*++cpp` points to `"GeksQuiz"`

`*--*++cpp` points to the beginning of the `"GeksQuiz"`, to its first character

Then you advance the resulting pointer by 3, resulting in the output you see.

Comment: how --*++cpp points to "GeksQuiz" -- sign should move pointer back to TEST?

Comment: you advance the pointer by one, dereference it (pointing to a particular spot in the list), then move to a "previous" member in the list

Comment: `cpp` was already pointing to "TEST" by the time the first `printf` was done

Comment: @YePhIcK; Its not `cpp` that is pointing to `TEST`, but its `*cpp`.

Comment: Yes-yes, I was just simplifying. Of course `cpp` is not directly pointing to it. it is pointing to a pointer that is pointing to `"TEST"` :)

Answer (score 2):

Initially:

```
0x100: "GeksQuiz"
0x200: "MCQ"
0x300: "TEST"
0x400: "QUIZ"
0x500: { 0x100, 0x200, 0x300, 0x400 } // c
0x600: { 0x518, 0x510, 0x508, 0x500 } // cp
0x700: 0x600 // cpp
```

After statement 1:

```
0x700: 0x608 // ++cpp = 0x608
// *cpp = 0x510
// **cpp = 0x300 = "TEST"
```

After statement 2:

```
0x700: 0x610 // ++cpp = 0x610
0x600: { 0x518, 0x510, 0x500, 0x500 } // --*++cpp = 0x500
// *--*++cpp = 0x100 = "GeksQuiz"
// *--*++cpp+3 = 0x103 = "sQuiz"
```

After statement 3:

```
// cpp = 0x610
// cpp[-2] = 0x518
// *cpp[-2] = 0x400 = "QUIZ"
// *cpp[-2]+3 0x403 = "Z"
```

After statement 4:

```
// cpp = 0x610
// cpp[-1] = 0x510
// cpp[-1][-1] = 0x200 = "MCQ"
// cpp[-1][-1]+1 = 0x201 = "CQ"
```